# the actual link permissions aren't used for anything - What about Ownership?

Tags: apache-2.4, file-permissions, symbolic-link, owner

After months of intermittent attempts to discover what was causing these Forbidden errors I've discovered evidence that strongly suggests Apache2 uses the actual link's ownership and group.

- I have a VPS running ubuntu 14.04
- I have apache2 setup and running.
- My default document root is /var/www/html

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  ```

The document root's full hierarchy of permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 21 root     root     4096 Jun 10  2014 /
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root     4096 Sep  7  2014 /var
drwxrwxr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 15 15:25 /var/www
drwxr-xr-x  2 jesse    jesse    4096 Nov 15 15:25 /var/www/html
```

I have symlinked /var/www under my home directory.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesse jesse 9 Sep  8  2014 /home/jesse/www -> /var/www/
```

Now because I have several versions of the site I'm working on I like to keep all the sites in /var/www and then symlink to the correct production version in /var/www/html

```
root@vpn:/home/jesse# ls -l /var/www/html/
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesse   jesse     16 Sep 29  2014 storytellingaustralia -> ../joomla_3.3.4/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesse   jesse     17 Oct  4  2014 tealeaftroubadours -> ../wordpress_4.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesse   jesse     17 Oct  5  2014 tealeaftroubadours.com.au -> ../wordpress_4.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wp-user wp-user   8 Nov 15 15:25 test -> ../test/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesse   jesse     19 Jun  9 20:36 wa.storyguild.org.au -> ../wordpress_4.2.2/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesse   jesse     19 Nov 15 13:32 windwanderer.com.au -> ../wordpress_4.3.1/
```

**Now Here Is The Anomoly**

The permissions are currently set as follows and the site is accessible as expected.

```
root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# ls -l test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wp-user wp-user 8 Nov 15 15:25 test -> ../test/

root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# ls -lLd test
drwxr-x--- 2 wp-user www-data 4096 Nov 15 15:24 test
```

However, If I then change the ownership of the link it's self apache2 serves me a "Forbidden" notice.

```
root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# chown -h www-data test

root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# ls -l test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data wp-user 8 Nov 15 15:25 test -> ../test/

root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# ls -lLd test
drwxr-x--- 2 wp-user www-data 4096 Nov 15 15:24 test
```

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /test/index.html on this server.

If I then change the ownership of the target to be the same

```
root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# chown www-data test

root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# ls -l test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data wp-user 8 Nov 15 15:25 test -> ../test/

root@vpn:/home/jesse/www/html# ls -lLd test
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 15 15:24 test
```

The site is accessible once more.

It seems that Apache2 requires links to be owned by the same user as owns the target.

Does anyone know if there is a setting that controls this behaviour or can shed any light on how, why or what this behaviour is for? All I can think of is that it was someone's bright idea for added security but has sure caused me a lot of headaches.

Comment: You forgot to look at the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SymlinksIfOwnerMatch` option gives exactly the behaviour you describe only following links if ownership matches.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul. My apologies for taking so long to come back here and see your fabulous answer. It's much appreciated. :-)